# Дописать текст в конец файла

Tags: c#

Как дописать данные построчно из `1.txt` в конец `2.txt` не удаляя данные из `1.txt`?

```
File.AppendAllText(а тут как);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText("путь_до_1.txt");
File.AppendAllText("путь_до_2.txt", readText);
```

Comment: быстро! Очень гут!

Answer (score 7):

Вот вариант без чтения всего второго файла в память:

```
File.AppendAllLines("2.txt", File.ReadLines("1.txt"));
```

---

`AppendAllText` требует на вход текст как строку, поэтому эту строку требуется считать в память *полностью*. Вариант с `ReadLines` читает файл построчно и пишет по мере чтения. (Впрочем, он тоже не застрахован от *очень* длинных строк.)

Comment: Почему вариант с `ReadLines` пишет по мере чтения? `ReadLines` же массив строк возвращает. Т.о. файл вычитывается весь, хоть и построчно. После чего выполняется запись.

Comment: @Vlad [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает не массив, а  IEnumerable, который будет считывать строки по мере его перечисления. Перечисление [произойдет](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,061dee6027996d69) 1 раз во время записи. Потому тут получается логика "Считать строку - записать строку" без загрузки всего файла в память.

Comment: @tym32167, а, спасибо. У меня в голове он почему-то в [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) преобразился. :)

Answer (score 2):

Когда то писал свой велосипед по копированию больших файлов, думаю это может кому-нибудь помочь

```
// Файл из которого копируется
string pathSource = @"1.txt";
// Файл куда
string pathNew = @"2.txt";
// Размер буфера копирования
var bufferSize = 1024;

using(var stream = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using(var writeStream = new FileStream(pathNew, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    // Конец файла
    var endPoint = writeStream.Length;
    // Буфер копирования
    var buffer = new Byte[bufferSize];
    // Байт прочитали
    var bytesRead = 0;

    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using(var writer  = new StreamWriter(writeStream)) {

        // Пропускаем все до конца
        writeStream.Seek(endPoint, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Пишем блоки
        while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0) {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

    }
}
```